# Updating contacts in mobile phone simulation

Tags: java, performance, static

I'm currently making a mobile phone simulation, using a custom object in an `ArrayList`. I was wondering if there was any difference in using these two following styles.

First style, creating a new instance of Contact in my update method as so:

```
private static void updateContact() {
    System.out.println("Enter a contact name to replace ");
    String oldName = scanner.nextLine();
    Contacts oldContact = mobilePhone.queryContact(oldName);
    if(oldContact == null) {
        System.out.println("Contact not found");
        return;
    }
    System.out.println("Enter a new contact name");
    String newName = scanner.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Enter a new phoneNumber");
    String newNumber = scanner.nextLine();
    Contacts newContact = new Contacts(newName, newNumber);
    mobilePhone.updateContact(oldContact, newContact);
```

Or using a static method I created in the Customer class which reads:

```
public static Contacts createContact(String name, String phoneNumber) {
    return new Contacts(name, phoneNumber);
}
```

And changing the update method so that it uses this static method:

```
private static void updateContact() {
    System.out.println("Enter a contact name to replace ");
    String oldName = scanner.nextLine();
    Contacts oldContact = mobilePhone.queryContact(oldName);
    if(oldContact == null) {
        System.out.println("Contact not found");
        return;
    }
    System.out.println("Enter a new contact name");
    String newName = scanner.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Enter a new phoneNumber");
    String newNumber = scanner.nextLine();
    Contacts newContact = Contacts.createContact(newName, newNumber);
    mobilePhone.updateContact(oldContact, newContact);

}
```

I was wondering if there was any difference in here, as I notice none syntactically. Is this a more efficient way of doing it?

Answer (score 1):

I haven't run any benchmarks, but I would expect using a static function would have a minor (probably unobservable) speed penalty. This is because the static method calls the constructor anyway, meaning you haven't eliminated any operations. You've likely added one via the indirection - I don't believe the Java compiler can optimize this away due to support for reflection.

Using the constructor directly is also clearer.